# Multi-Index two columns, both of which have a common index

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
Connector  Pin           Adj. 
F123       1             [2, 6, 7]
           2       [1, 3, 6, 7, 8]
           3       [2, 4, 7, 8, 9]
           4      [3, 5, 8, 9, 10]
           5            [4, 9, 10]
           6             [1, 2, 7]
           7       [1, 2, 3, 6, 8]
           8       [2, 3, 4, 7, 9]
           9      [3, 4, 5, 8, 10]
           10            [4, 5, 9]
C137       1                [2, 3]
           2                [1, 3]
           3                [1, 2]
```

Both Connector and Pin are multi-indexed, however, is it possible to also multi index that same Connector value with Adj.?

The code below is what I figured would be the ticket:

```
df = df.reset_index().set_index(['Connector' , 'Pin'])['Adj.']
df = df.reset_index().set_index(['Connector' , 'Pin']['Connector' , 'Adj.'])
```

On the second line I get the following error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

First off, I thought this was a list and not a tuple. If it is a tuple, is it possible to convert this already populated tuple to a list of integers and then multi-index it back with Connector?

Update:
I am trying to make it so the dataframe has two columns at the end, not just one column with all 3 indexed together. So like a table that has the index value ('F123', 1) and then another 'Adj.' column that has ('F123', 2), ('F123', 6), ('F123', 7)---> all of which have the same index--->('F123', 1)

Expected Output (I think):

```
Connector  Pin   Connector   Adj. 
F123       1       F123       2
           1       F123       6
           1       F123       7
```

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54426410/edit) to include your desired output?

Comment: @jpp Updated with what I think it should be (kinda hard to picture it)